# Cassandra Batch query with USING TIMESTAMP

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

Hi i am working with Cassandra Batch. Cassandra executes statement based on current timestamp. I have following scenario

public class CassandraBatchExample {

```
public static String query1="BEGIN BATCH "
        + "insert into studentbyfname(fname,lname,feeamount,rollnum)values(‘abc’,’xyz’,100,1) USING TIMESTAMP 11; "
        + "delete from  studentbyfname USING TIMESTAMP 10 where fname=‘abc’ and lname=‘xyz’;”
        + "APPLY BATCH";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cluster cluster = null;
    Session session =null;

    try{

         cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("127.0.0.1","127.0.0.2").build();
         session = cluster.connect("demokeyspace");
         session.execute(query1);        

    }catch(Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
    }finally {
        session.close();
        cluster.close();
    }

}
```

}

When i execute above piece of code nothing happens to the DB side.
Cassandra should insert record in the table since insert statement inside batch has more current timestamp than delete statement.

**Note:= This is strange now, today i ran this code and it inserted record into the table but it is behaving in an unexpected manner, sometime it insert records sometime it does not.**

Can somebody help me on this ? Am i missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the timestamp should be expressed in `epoch` Example `1540400659000000` microseconds. Please check the references in the manual
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlBatch.html